# Foreach, for loop PHP redundancy

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have the following code:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <?php $sql = "SELECT book_id, book_name FROM book ORDER BY book_name";
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("...");
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
                $myId   = $row['book_id'];
                $myName = $row['book_name'];
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
                    if ($myId != $array[$i]) {
                        echo("<option value='$myId'>$myName</option>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
        ...
        }
        $conn = null;
    ?>
</select>
```

My purpose is to have a selector `<select>`, where the not previously associated books with the user appear. In this case, the $array holds the Id of the books that are already link to this user.

I know the problem is the nested loop, because I got the result I want, eg (for a $row = 3 and a $i = 2):

```
Book1
Book1
Book2
Book2
Book3
Book3
```

And the desired result would be:

```
Book1
Book2
Book3
```

But I can't figured out how to compared the Id's, without nesting the loops.

Comment: Can you clearly show us what your desired output would be, given a certain input?

Comment: Can you please show what is actually in `$array`, it's not clear what's going on and what you want.

Comment: where do you set your $array? also: have you tried `in_array()`? it prevents you from looping over $array yourself

Comment: The $array comes from another query, where all the book_id associated to the user are inserted, e.g: $array = [1,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of your for-loop

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
                    if ($myId != $array[$i]) {
                        echo("<option value='$myId'>$myName</option>");
                    }
                }
```

try in_array() instad:

```
if(!in_array($myId, $array)) {
    echo("<option value='$myId'>$myName</option>");
}
```

even if $array contains $id multiple times, this will only write once.

edit: forgot the `!` to negate. the condition.

Comment: Will try this approach also!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself, I can't believe I didn't break the second loop:

```
       foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
            $myId   = $row['book_id'];
            $myName = $row['book_name'];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
                if ($myId != $array[$i]) {
                    echo("<option value='$myId'>$myName</option>");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```